# asp.net caching

Tags: asp.net, caching

net and i jus recently completed a small application using asp.net. The problem i am having is that when a user clicks a button to logout i am calling the following:

```
Session.Abondon(); 
if (Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"] != null)
{
     Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value = string.Empty;
     Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-20);
 }
```

Now when they click the back button on their browser window they are able to see the exact page they were on. how can i stop this from happening?
Please help.

Comment: thats not a good way to end a session with the code you have.

Comment: @David: That may be true but for a reader to assess such a statement you ought to include the reason why its not good.

Comment: Whats the best way to end a session?